# Trouble with libgdx and libgdx-sql lite

Tags: java, android, libgdx

everything worked perfectly and when i tried to debug my game i got error:

**Program type already present: com.badlogic.gdx.sql.Database
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.badlogic.gdx.sql.Database, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}**

I'm using libgdx and gdx-sqlite (in android studio) which i downloaded and followed instructions from here :

https://github.com/mrafayaleem/gdx-sqlite

There is nothing wrong with my code because all worked until few days ago. I searched a lot and i couldn't find any solution for this. I think that there is some problem with gradle or something.

Here is Logcat:

```
    04-25 09:29:53.903 2771-689/? I/EventLogChimeraService: Aggregate from 1524575042536 (log), 1524575042536 (data)

    --------- beginning of system
04-25 09:41:34.642 1504-1532/system_process W/BatteryStatsImpl: Couldn't get kernel wake lock stats
04-25 09:41:58.199 2717-570/? E/WakeLock: release without a matched acquire!
04-25 09:43:00.003 1504-1526/system_process I/ProcessStatsService: Prepared write state in 1ms
04-25 09:45:21.787 1504-1512/system_process I/art: Debugger is no longer active
04-25 09:45:21.818 3886-3894/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
04-25 09:45:21.836 2424-2433/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
04-25 09:45:21.862 447-455/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
04-25 09:45:21.866 426-435/com.google.android.calendar I/art: Debugger is no longer active
04-25 09:45:21.868 2622-2630/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
04-25 09:45:21.873 2533-2559/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/art: Debugger is no longer active
04-25 09:45:21.882 3139-3147/com.android.deskclock I/art: Debugger is no longer active
04-25 09:45:21.882 2288-2297/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
04-25 09:45:21.891 18720-18730/com.google.android.gms.ui I/art: Debugger is no longer active
04-25 09:45:21.895 2311-2320/android.process.acore I/art: Debugger is no longer active
04-25 09:45:21.898 2771-2781/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
04-25 09:45:21.899 2664-2685/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox I/art: Debugger is no longer active
04-25 09:45:21.903 3917-3925/com.svox.pico I/art: Debugger is no longer active
04-25 09:45:21.907 2664-2685/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.107ms
04-25 09:45:21.908 2485-2504/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
04-25 09:45:21.909 14575-14583/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
04-25 09:45:21.916 2717-2726/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
04-25 09:45:21.921 2424-2433/? W/art: Suspending all threads took: 84.509ms
04-25 09:45:21.925 2462-2472/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
04-25 09:45:21.929 1504-1512/system_process W/art: Suspending all threads took: 43.796ms
04-25 09:45:21.938 2717-2726/? W/art: Suspending all threads took: 21.604ms
04-25 09:45:21.939 2462-2472/? W/art: Suspending all threads took: 12.494ms
04-25 09:45:21.956 2771-2781/? W/art: Suspending all threads took: 32.577ms
04-25 09:45:31.416 1504-2549/system_process D/AlarmManagerService: Kernel timezone updated to -120 minutes west of GMT
04-25 09:45:31.443 1504-3194/system_process D/AlarmManagerService: Setting time of day to sec=1524642505
04-25 09:48:25.590 3139-3139/com.android.deskclock V/AlarmClock: AlarmInitReceiver android.intent.action.TIME_SET
04-25 09:48:25.730 3139-3156/com.android.deskclock V/AlarmClock: AlarmInitReceiver finished
```

build.gradle (Project: Unicorn-Android):

buildscript {

```
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "Unicorns"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.8'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.3'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile files("libs/gdx-sqlite-android/jar");
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

build.grade (Module:android) :

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    compileSdkVersion 27
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/robovm/ios/robovm.xml'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dusan.unicorn"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() {
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
        if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if (outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}
task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.example.dusan.unicorn/com.example.dusan.unicorn.AndroidLauncher'
}
// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitly, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [project.configurations.compile]
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'
    }

    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}
// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [COMPILE: [plus: [project.configurations.compile]]]

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value: "true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/gdx-sqlite-android.jar')
    implementation files('libs/gdx-sqlite.jar')
}
```

build.gradle (Module:core)

```
    apply plugin: "java"
sourceCompatibility = 1.6
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ["src/"]
eclipse.project {
    name = appName + "-core"
}
dependencies {
    implementation files('build/libs/gdx-sqlite-android.jar')
    implementation files('build/libs/gdx-sqlite.jar')
}
```

build.gradle (Module: desktop)

```
apply plugin: "java"
sourceCompatibility = 1.6
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]
project.ext.mainClassName = "com.example.dusan.unicorn.desktop.DesktopLauncher"
project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../android/assets");

task run(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
}
task debug(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
    debug = true
}
task dist(type: Jar) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir)
    from {configurations.compile.collect {zipTree(it)}}
    from files(project.assetsDir);

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }
}

dist.dependsOn classes
eclipse {
    project {
        name = appName + "-desktop"
        linkedResource name: 'assets', type: '2', location: 'PARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC/android/assets'
    }
}
task afterEclipseImport(description: "Post processing after project generation", group: "IDE") {
  doLast {
    def classpath = new XmlParser().parse(file(".classpath"))
    new Node(classpath, "classpathentry", [ kind: 'src', path: 'assets' ]);
    def writer = new FileWriter(file(".classpath"))
    def printer = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer))
    printer.setPreserveWhitespace(true)
    printer.print(classpath)
  }
}
```

So my question is : does anyone has some idea what could be the problem ?
If you need some additional information just ask. Sorry for my English. Thanks in advance.

here is one more error

```
org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':android:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:139)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:109)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':android:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultExceptionAnalyser.transform(DefaultExceptionAnalyser.java:74)
    at org.gradle.initialization.MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.transform(MultipleBuildFailuresExceptionAnalyser.java:47)
    at org.gradle.initialization.StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.transform(StackTraceSanitizingExceptionAnalyser.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:137)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:109)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:11
```

Comment: Btw here is one more error which i forgot to add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also here is my part of code for database (which i copy pasted 90% from link i provided above)

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.sql.Database;
import com.badlogic.gdx.sql.DatabaseCursor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.sql.DatabaseFactory;
import com.badlogic.gdx.sql.SQLiteGdxException;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import helpers.Boxes;


public class GameScreenContract {

    Database dbHandler;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "GameScreenTable";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_LEVEL= "level";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_POSITIONX = "positionX";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_POSITIONY = "positionY";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "unicornDb.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database creation sql statement
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table if not exists "
            + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COLUMN_ID  + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + COLUMN_NAME_LEVEL + " integer not null, "
            + COLUMN_NAME_POSITIONX + " integer not null, "
            + COLUMN_NAME_POSITIONY + " integer not null"
            + ");";

    public GameScreenContract(){
        Gdx.app.log("DatabaseTest", "creation started");

        OpenDB();
    }

    public void OpenDB(){
        dbHandler = DatabaseFactory.getNewDatabase(DATABASE_NAME,
                DATABASE_VERSION, DATABASE_CREATE, null);

        dbHandler.setupDatabase();
        try {
            dbHandler.openOrCreateDatabase();
            dbHandler.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        } catch (SQLiteGdxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Gdx.app.log("DatabaseTest", "created successfully");
    }

    public void SavePositions(ArrayList<Boxes> boxes){

        try {
            dbHandler.execSQL("DELETE from " + TABLE_NAME);
        } catch (SQLiteGdxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(Boxes box : boxes) {
            try {
                dbHandler.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " ('" + COLUMN_NAME_LEVEL + "', '" + COLUMN_NAME_POSITIONX + "', '" + COLUMN_NAME_POSITIONY + "')"
                        + " VALUES ('"+ box.Level + "', " + box.x + ", "+ box.positionForFallenBox + ")");
            } catch (SQLiteGdxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        try {
            dbHandler.closeDatabase();
        } catch (SQLiteGdxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dbHandler = null;
        Gdx.app.log("DatabaseTest", "dispose");
    }

    public void GetAllData(){
       DatabaseCursor cursor = null;
       ArrayList<Boxes> boxes = new ArrayList<Boxes>();

        try {
            cursor = dbHandler.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME);
        } catch (SQLiteGdxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (cursor.next()) {
            int level = cursor.getInt(1);
            int x = cursor.getInt(2);
            int y = cursor.getInt(3);
            Boxes b = new Boxes(level, x, y);
            boxes.add(b);

            Gdx.app.log("lvl", level + "");
            Gdx.app.log("X", x + "");
            Gdx.app.log("Y", y + "");
        }

        Gdx.app.log("DatabaseTest", "dispose");

        //return boxes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19547569)

Comment: I tried that but i exceeded limit for characters that's why i post as an answer

Comment: i just figured that after i rebuild project, sql-lite.jar from /core/libs get deleted for some reason. Everything works fine until i rebuild project. Since i do that sql-lite.jar get deleted instantly . And still don't know how to fix that

Comment: Seems like the problem was at my HDD ... After i pulled my project from gitlab to another pc everything was fine even i rebuld project. No files are deleted got no errors everything work just fine as it should. :)